# Rails 3, bootstrap modal multiple layers of remote calling

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, modal-dialog, twitter-bootstrap

I've been racking my head against this for 2 days now.  I'm massively frustrated, and I can't seem to find any information on this with searching.

The issue.  I'm using a :remote => true link to load some html from a different controller.

```
$('.managed_locations').bind('ajax:complete', function(evt, xhr, status){
    $('#locations_modal').modal('show')
    $('#locations_modal').html(xhr.responseText);
});
```

So it gets the html, dumps it into the bootstrap modal and displays the modal. This is working fine.

But inside of the modal I ALSO have a form which also uses :remote => true.  Now to make life harder, when a button is pressed I clone the form and display it.  So the user could have many forms.

Now the issue.  Whenever the form is submitted it just loads it like a normal page.  It's as if the :remote => true is being ignored.  But this only in the modal.  If I just load the modal controller by itself it works just fine.  I also had this developed before using another jquery lightbox where it was working fine.  I'm just switching in bootstrap for consistency.

So my initial thoughts are that the jquery_ujs.js isn't finding the new forms.  So I added some code to output the form elements.

```
$("#log_events").click(function () {
$(document).find(".new_stored_physical_location").each(function() {
    console.log( $(this).data() );
    console.log( $(this).data('events') );
});
return false;
});
```

Which outputs in the console:

```
Object { type="html", remote=true}
Object { ajax:complete=[1]}
```

So I see that the events are being set in jQuery.  Each of these forms has :remote => true and has the ajax event for when the request is complete.  But it's just not doing an ajax request when I hit submit.

**Is there something I'm missing that is required to make sure an ajax request will happen from the form????**  The data() looks fine, the data('events') look fine. But is there some other event/binding that I need to look at?

The html that is loaded in from the modal right now is loading a layout.  But i've done it both with a layout, without a layout.  It's driving me nuts.  Thanks for the help guys.

**Edit:** Some extra weirdness.  The modal also loads some additional remote links, all of which are working correctly.  It's only the form links which don't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

I got a solution.  The big issue was within jquery_ujs.js  Especially this line:

```
$(document).delegate(rails.formSubmitSelector, 'submit.rails', function(e) {
```

FYI, rails.formSubmitSelector = 'form'.  So this code found all of the forms in the document, overwrote the submit with this function.  But the issue was that once you loaded in some ajax, and that ajax contained a  it wouldn't add this fancy event to it.  You need to re-add it.

So this is what I did.

Inside of jquery_ujs there is a bunch of functions that are accessible outside of it using $.rails.  So things like:  $.rails.enableElement, $.rails.nonBlankInputs.  And the code for the submit event was sitting around all willy nilly.  It only executes once when the page is loaded.  So I put that in a function addSubmitEvent():

```
// Add the form submit event
addSubmitEvent: function(element) {

  //$(element) was before $(document) but I changed it
  $(element).delegate(rails.formSubmitSelector, 'submit.rails', function(e) {


    var form = $(this),
      remote = form.data('remote') !== undefined,
      blankRequiredInputs = rails.blankInputs(form, rails.requiredInputSelector),
      nonBlankFileInputs = rails.nonBlankInputs(form, rails.fileInputSelector);

    if (!rails.allowAction(form)) return rails.stopEverything(e);

    // skip other logic when required values are missing or file upload is present
    if (blankRequiredInputs && form.attr("novalidate") == undefined && rails.fire(form, 'ajax:aborted:required', [blankRequiredInputs])) {
      return rails.stopEverything(e);
    }

    if (remote) {
      if (nonBlankFileInputs) {
        return rails.fire(form, 'ajax:aborted:file', [nonBlankFileInputs]);
      }

      // If browser does not support submit bubbling, then this live-binding will be called before direct
      // bindings. Therefore, we should directly call any direct bindings before remotely submitting form.
      if (!$.support.submitBubbles && $().jquery < '1.7' && rails.callFormSubmitBindings(form, e) === false) return rails.stopEverything(e);

      rails.handleRemote(form);
      return false;

    } else {
      // slight timeout so that the submit button gets properly serialized
      setTimeout(function(){ rails.disableFormElements(form); }, 13);
    }
  });

}
```

This is basically the exact same code. But now it's $(element) instead of $(document).  This was changed because now I can sniff for when the modal has loaded in the html. Then I can call:

```
$.rails.addSubmitEvent('#my_modal');
```

I then had an issue of it adding the event too many times from when I opened/closed the modal multiple times. So I just put a simple true/false if around it to call it once only.